# How to build this predicate for use with Find?

Tags: haskell, predicate

I want to return a String in a list that contains only Digits. I am trying to use the find function to achieve this but am having trouble creating the predicate.  Here is what I have attempted:

```
getYear str | hasYear str = fromJust $ find (map and $ (map.map) isDigit ws) ws
            | otherwise = "0"
                where ws = words str
```

I have noticed that my predicate

```
map and $ (map.map) isDigit ws
```

returns a [Bool] with True if one of the Strings contains only digits but isn't designed correctly for use in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also the handy

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

which can be used to write your function

```
find (all isDigit)
```

Comment: Did not know about all. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
find (\ws -> and $ map isDigit ws) ws
```

Comment: Use `all isDigit ws` instead of `and $ map isDigit ws`.

Comment: The reason being `all = and .: map`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that case, when String do not contain the year with `fromMaybe`.

```
getYear = fromMaybe "0" . find (all isDigit) . words
```

For example,

```
λ> fromMaybe "0" . find (all isDigit) $ words "sdf"
"0"

λ> fromMaybe "" . find (all isDigit) $ words "42139 213 f dsf 2"
"42139"
```

**UPD**: on the other hand, input String may have some digits, but `hasYear` return `False`. That why you shouldn't handle case, when `find` returns `Nothing` because it will never happened.

And than your `getYear` may looks like that:

```
getYear str | hasYear str = fromJust . find (all isDigit) . words $ str
            | otherwise = "0"
```